# Javascript recursion example trouble

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
const writeText = function(word, n) {
  if(n >= 5) {
    return '';
  }
  n = n + 1;
  return word + writeText(word + n);
};

debugger;

writeText('hello', 1);
```

I want to write a code which will return 'hello1', 'hello2', ... 'hello5' using recursion.
My code didn't work so I used debugger to see what's wrong. It shows that after the first recursive call, **n** turns into **undefined**. Can anyone help me out and show what's wrong with this code?

Comment: And where exactly do you expect `n` to come from, when you call the function with only _one_ parameter `writeText(word + n)` ...?

Comment: Is there a way to do this with only one parameter? Is it a good idea to define it beforehand?

Comment: _Why_? You wrote your function to expect two parameters, so why would you want to withhold one from it now, instead of just passing it, same way as you are doing in the initial call?

Comment: Ahh sorry, didn't notice. Now I get what you're saying. Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

- When using recursive calls, you better use a named function instead of a function expression, because the name does not change with assingment of the function. This is necessary for recursive calling, which might call a unknown function.
- Exit function if the value is greater than `5`.
- You need to display the actual value of `n` (and maybe a new line).
- Call the function with the word and a second parameter of the incremented value.

```js
function writeText(word, n) {
    if (n > 5) {
        return '';
    }
    return word + n + '\n' + writeText(word, n + 1);
};

console.log(writeText('hello', 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there - the answer provided by @Nina Scholz is good.

Here an approach you could use using ES6 template literals to keep us up to date.

Since you're new some comments about the syntax which you could google:

`` => : arrow functions
`text` : template literals ``

```js
const writeText = (word, n) => 
  `${word+n} ${n < 5 ? writeText(word, n+1) : ''}`;
 
console.log(writeText('hello',1))
```

```